# Why does my Fibonacci take so long when the dictionary is in the function?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, fibonacci

Here I have some code to return the last digit of a Fibonacci number. When I place the cache dictionary inside the function the program works fine for small n. When I try larger n like 300 the program takes forever. When I make the dictionary global, however, I get an instant result for a larger n like 300. What's causing such a sharp performance difference between the dictionary being declared in function vs outside of the function?

```
def fib_last_digit_mem(n):
    cache = {}

    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]

    if(n <= 1):
        return n

    fib = (fib_last_digit_mem(n-1) + fib_last_digit_mem(n-2))%10
    cache[n] = fib
    return fib
```

Answer (score 7):

Since this is a recursive function if you instantiate the cache inside the function it will be instantiated again every time the function recurses. This also means the cache is always empty so you never take the short route `if n in cache`

Answer (score 4):

You aren't actually caching anything, because the *local* var `cache` is initialized to an empty dict every time you call the function. Sure, once you compute the value you add it to the dict. But then you return: `cache` goes out of scope, and the `dict` is garbage-collected.

You need some reference to `cache` that exists *outside* `fib_last_digit_mem`, but that doesn't necessarily need to be a global variable.

Consider:

```
def make_cached_fib():
    cache = {}
    def _(n):
        if n in cache:
            return cache[n]
        if n <= 1:
            return n
        fib = (_(n-1) + _(n-2)) % 10
        cache[n] = fib
        return fib
    return _

fib_last_digit_mem = make_cached_fib()
```

Here, the cache is not global; it's in scope where `fib_last_digit_mem` is defined. Once `make_cached_fib` returns, the only reference to the cache is the one held by `fib_last_digit_mem` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate the cache inside the function which is called recursively. This leads to two problems:

1) Each time you do a recursive call, you have to instantiate a cache which costs a bit of performance, but that creation process isnt the reason your code is running slow.

2) The real reason and even bigger problem is that youre not doing anything with your cache. Dynamic programming allows you to reuse previously calculated results, so you dont have to calculate them again. You save these results in the cache. But because youre intantiating the cache everytime you call the method all your recursive calls end up having an own empty local cache instead of sharing one global cache which helps you to avoid calculating previosuly calculated results again.

Example:

If you declare the cache globally and calculate `fibonacci(10)` the last operation just has to get the result of `fibonacci(9)` out of the cache and add another number to it. Its only one addition to calculate the next n-th fibonacci-number. In your case, instead of just getting the result of `fibonacci(9)` and adding a number to it, youre actually calculating `fibonacci(9)` again, which means you have to calcualte `fibonacci(8)` again etc... That causes the bad performance without dynamic programming(global cache)